# Terms in conditions in installer or is on website ok

Tags: applications, installer, terms-of-service

I am currently in the process of packing my first c# wpf app.

The app will be paid so it requires the user to agree to some terms and conditions.

Is it best to have these built into the installer? Or can I get away with having the user accept them on the website they buy them from during the purchase and before download the app?

Comment: One important point for including them in the installer is that it's clear which version of your ToS / EULA your user agreed to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The app will be paid so it requires the user to agree to some terms and conditions.

Really? In my country, courts have ruled that nobody actually reads all the legalese and nobody in their right mind can really *expect* people to read this, so it's not a binding contract anyway.

If anyone had to read *and* understand *and* agree to Apples ToS, they would not have sold a single iProduct. Companies' business model includes customers clicking through all the "terms and conditions".

- If you want people to read anything you write, put it where they *will* read it. Put in in simple sentences next to their credit card number when they pay. Simple sentences means one, maybe two paragraphs and no legalese. This is how you get information across.
- If you need 9 pages of legalese to make your application look "commercial", feel free to put it whereever you want.
- If you need a binding contract, consult a lawyer, this probably won't work without actual paperwork between you and your customer.